# If X converge to zero does its infinite mean

Tags: convergence

Let $X_t \in \mathbb{R^+}$, $t = 1, ...,T$. Suppose we know that for all $t$, $X_t = o_p(1)$, (i.e. $X_t$ goes to zero in probability as $T \to \infty$). As $T \to \infty$, can we conclude that

$$
\frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^{T} X_t = o_p(1) ?
$$

Comment: The notation needs fixing.  Are you describing one sequence of iid random variables, in which case the answer is "yes, the mean is zero".  Or are you describing $T$ sequences of iid rvs, with each $X_t$ being some sequence $(X_{t,n})_{n=1,\ldots,\infty}$ converging in probability to zero?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In this case, $X_t$ is assumed to be identically distributed with some dependence that goes away as $T$ goes to infinity. Can you kindly provide some useful reference for the case of iid random variable?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Weak_law

Comment: @Creosote (and the OP): How can the $X_t$ be identically distributed and $o_p(1)$ without being equal to $0 \, \forall \, t$?

Answer (score 0):

The following demonstrates that when $(X_t)$ converges in probability to zero, it is **not** necessarily the case that the running mean also converges in probability to zero.

---

Set $X_t=0$ with probability $\frac{t-1}{t}$, and $X_t=2t$ with probability $\frac{1}{t}$.

Clearly, $(X_t)$ converges in probability to zero.

Let $Y_t=\frac{1}{t}\sum_{i=1}^tX_i$ be the running mean.

A sufficient condition for $Y_{2t}\ge 1$ is that not all of $X_{t+1},\ldots,X_{2t}$ are zero:
$$
\mathbb{P}(Y_{2t}\ge 1) \ \ \ge \ \ 1 \ - \ \tfrac{t}{t+1}\cdot\tfrac{t+1}{t+2}\cdots\tfrac{2t-1}{2t} \ \ = \ \ \tfrac{1}{2}
$$
Thus, $(Y_{2t})$ does not converge in probability to zero; so neither does $(Y_t$).